# Use Maps API to calculate distance of two addresses then save each distance to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps-api-3, open-uri

I'm writing an app which matches children to kindergartens based on the distance.

I am trying to use the Maps API to calculate distances between multiple addresses.
I want to use open-uri

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=[address of child]&destinations=[adress of kindergarden]&key=XYZ
```

that would be the request for the api.

My idea was to send the request after the creation process of the child.
I would take the child address and the kindergarten address from the database and build the request.
The responded distance would be saved in a relations table for each child and kindergarten
How can I access the database entries of the child and the kindergartens?
And then save it to the relations table?

My current code looks as follows:

```
def create
    @child = Child.new child_params
    @child.user = current_user
    @child.save
    origin = @child.adress
    destination = @kiga.adress
    response = open('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=' + [address of child] + '&destinations=' + [adress of kindergarden] + '&key=XYZ').read
    relations.distance = response.rows.elements[0]

    respond_to do |format|
      if @child.save
        format.html { redirect_to @child, notice: 'Child was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @child }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @child.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
```

Help would be appreciated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that you are trying to open the URL as a string, so it's looking for a file named that way and it does not exist.

You have two options here:

### 1. Use HTTParty gem to make HTTP requests

This one is my favourite approach.

Include the gem in your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'HTTParty'
```

Make the request within your controller:

```
url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=" \
      "#{@child.adress}&destinations=#{@kiga.adress}&key=XYZ"
response = HTTParty.get(url)
```

Now if you were to print out the result of `response["rows"].first["elements"].first` you would see an output like this:

```
{"distance"=>{"text"=>"15.4 km", "value"=>15405}, "duration"=>{"text"=>"17 mins", "value"=>1001}, "status"=>"OK"}
```

As you can see you have distance as well as duration information. I am guessing you are after the distance value in meters so:

```
relations.distance = response["rows"].first["elements"].first["distance"]["value"]
```

**NOTE 1**: I intentionally reproduced the typo in the word address (@child.adress, @kiga.adress) so that the code works with your setup, but give a thought to fixing it to @child.address and @kiga.address.

**NOTE 2**: For simplicity I did not do any error checking on the response, that's something you should definitely take care of.

**NOTE 3**: Remember to change the api key to a valid one, I hardcoded it for simplicity to XYZ like you did in your question.

### 2. Use open-uri to parse your url into a valid URI

You have to require the libraries `'open-uri'` and `'JSON'` in the beginning of the controller:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'JSON'

    def create
    @child = Child.new child_params
    @child.user = current_user
    @child.save
    origin = @child.adress
    destination = @kiga.adress
    
    # Parse the string url into a valid URI
    url = URI.parse(
        "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=" \
        "#{@child.adress}&destinations=#{@kiga.adress}&key=XYZ"
    )
    # Open the URI just like you were doing
    response = open(url).read
    # Parse the string response in JSON format
    result = JSON.parse(response)

    # Extract the distance value in meters
    relations.distance = result["rows"].first["elements"].first["distance"]["value"]

    respond_to do |format|
        if @child.save
            format.html { redirect_to @child, notice: 'Child was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @child }
        else
            format.html { render :new }
            format.json { render json: @child.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
end
```

The contents of the variable `result` (after parsing it) look like the following:

```
{"destination_addresses"=>["Destination address"], "origin_addresses"=>["Origin address"], "rows"=>[{"elements"=>[{"distance"=>{"text"=>"15.4 km", "value"=>15405}, "duration"=>{"text"=>"17 mins", "value"=>1001}, "status"=>"OK"}]}], "status"=>"OK"}
```

---

Either if you go for the HTTParty way or the open-uri + JSON parsing way, make sure you check the response status codes. Both approaches have been tested locally on my computer with successful results.

I hope it helps, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

One alternative solution would be to look at this Gem 
https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder

If you Geocode your Child Model and your Kiga Model then you can easily get a distance from one to the other.

```
enter code here
```

This is without doing any API call, the GEM does this for you.

It does also have a very handy method to return records nearby a location

```
@kiga.near(@child.coordinates, 10)
```

would return all Kiga with 10km of @child coordinates